# How to export multiple selected rows in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a problem with exporting a list. I want to export multiple selected rows in a DataGridView to Excel. I have added one column in the DataGridView which is chkCheck and it is columncheckbox for the other I just use SQL Server

[image]

Here is the picture. I might have 10 rows of data but I want to select only several of them to export

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As New Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim excelLocation As String = ""


    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        excelLocation = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\Export-" & Format(Now(), "MMMM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") & ".xlsx"
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)

        'Export Header Names Start
        Dim columnsCount As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 6
        For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 6
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
        Next
        'Export Header Name End


        'Export Each Row Start
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each selectedrow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
            Do Until columnIndex = columnsCount
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, columnIndex + 1).Value = selectedrow.Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString
                columnIndex += 1
            Loop
            i += 1
        Next
        'Export Each Row End

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(excelLocation)
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()


        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    Else
        MsgBox("Save have been canceled", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Warning")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If the data source of your datagridview is a datatable, you can use a dataview to filter only the rows that were selected and loop thru those rows only.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b im sorry but im kinda new and dont know how to do that T-T and im self study by youtube and google

Comment: Please explain what the problem is with your code. Are you getting an error? What is the error? Where is the code does it occur? How is the result different from what you require?

Comment: @Mary it does not occur error but i want to know how i can check several checkbox in datagridview and export only the one i checked and why my coding just export one data even  when i check the checkbox 2 data

Comment: The current code appears to be exporting the rows that are “selected.” If you wanted to export only the rows that have been “checked”, then you would loop through the entire grid and check which cells in column zero (0) have been “checked.” Note you will want to check if the check box cell is `null` BEFORE you attempt to get its `Value`. If the cell is `null` then obviously the check box cell is NOT checked.

Comment: Possibly a little more advanced.  Through proper use of databindings, this all becomes quite a lot easier.  You can read your spreadsheet into a in memory collection (eg DataTable) Bind your grid to that, then it's almost a single line of code (Linq expression) to select the records you're after.  Common trap is to use the UI to process data, where possible use the underlying data objects which doesn't have the UI overheads.

Comment: @JohnG i will try that

Comment: @Hursey i kinda not understand that but thank you..im new with this

Comment: You should take note of  @Hursey 's comment... that would be the better approach.

Comment: @JohnG i want but i dont undertsand how

Comment: @JohnG it okay i already got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Reference
Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel

Private Sub Export_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls"
        sfd.ValidateNames = True
        If sfd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim rowstotal, colstotal, i, j, k As Integer
            Dim excelapp As New Excel.Application
            Try
                Dim excelbook As Excel.Workbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Add
                Dim excelworksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelbook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

                rowstotal = DataGridView1.RowCount
                colstotal = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                With excelworksheet
                    For k = 0 To colstotal
                        .Cells(1, k + 1).value = DataGridView1.Columns(k).HeaderText
                    Next

                    For i = 0 To rowstotal - 1 ' rows details
                        Dim selectcl As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("chkcolumn").Value)
                        If selectcl = 1 Then
                            For j = 0 To colstotal
                                .Cells(i + 2, j + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                            Next j
                        End If
                    Next i

                    .Rows("1:1").font.fontstyle = "Bold"
                    .Rows("1:1").font.size = 12
                End With
                excelbook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName)
                excelapp.Quit()
                MessageBox.Show("Exported Sucessfully")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            'Export Each Row Start
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim checkselect As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells("chkCheck").Value)
            If checkselect = 1 Then
                For columnIndex As Integer = 1 To columnsCount - 1
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, columnIndex + 1).Value = row.Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString
                Next
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
        'Export Each Row End
```

this my code that i try for export each row part ..thanks for helping

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).